# too many soql queries error 101 - using process Builder

Tags: apex, process-builder, email-template

I've researched answers on here regarding error 101 but cannot resolve or understand quite where the errors are. I have a scheduled class that updates rows in an object once a day. Basically, it changes the status to 'Ready to send' (usually about 1,000 records). I have a process that sends an email (using a class with invocable variables) if the field changes to 'Ready to send'. I can do 50 when I use limit 50 but this is no good. is the limit reached when the process is triggered ? Thanks for looking. Here is my class;

```
global class ScheduleEmailInvoices implements Schedulable {


global void execute(SchedulableContext sc) {


List<Email_Notifications__c > acclist = [Select SendStatus__c,QualifyDate__c from Email_Notifications__c where SendStatus__c = 'Completed' and QualifyDate__c =Today];



        for(Email_Notifications__c a: acclist)

        {

               a.SendStatus__c = 'Ready to send';

        }
        update acclist;

 }
 }
```

[image: process]

Comment: What else is in that object? What does the Process Builder do? We're missing some valuable context here

Comment: The object holds person email, sender email, template I'd. These are used to populate the email send class.

Comment: The process builder sends the email using the email send class

Comment: We can't help you if you don't show us details.....

Comment: Which details do you require

Comment: i have taken a snapshot image of the process but not sure how to add it here

Comment: You can [edit] your question to include the screenshot and info regarding the process builder.

Comment: thanks Kris....

Comment: Think I've resolved this. Will test tomorrow and update to help others. Thanks